# Background-position property does not work inside keyframes - tailwind config file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve an animation on a gradient that i have and I have setup my animation as well and keyframe in tailwind config file

they are inside theme->extend , I have configured them correctly since, I have tested the code by adding opacity inside keyframe they work as expected but when i add **background-position** attribute they are not working . config file looks like bellow

```js
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        mainLoading: "mainLoading 1s ease infinite",
      },
      keyframes: {
        mainLoading: {
          "0%": {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
          "50%": {
            "background-position": "100% 0%",
          },
          "100%": {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    colors: {
      transparent: "transparent",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix: "tw-",
};
```

I am using the above animation like bellow in my js file

```
 <div className="tw-absolute tw-top-0 tw-left-0 tw-w-full tw-h-full tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-text-center tw-justify-center tw-z-20 tw-bg-gradient-to-r tw-from-white tw-via-gray-300 tw-bg-size-200 tw-animate-mainLoading">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `theme.colors` which means that this completely overrides the default Tailwind palette and means that `white` and `gray-300` are not recognized as colors for the `tw-from-white` and `tw-via-gray-300` classes respectively. Consider setting your `transparent` color in `theme.extend.colors.transparent` instead.

Furthermore, the background gradient is the same size as the element, which means `background-position: 0% 0%` and `background-position: 100% 0%` essentially mean the same thing. Consider setting a `background-size` in the x-axis that is not the same size as the element it is set on.

```js
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        transparent: "transparent",
      },
      animation: {
        mainLoading: "mainLoading 1s ease infinite",
      },
      keyframes: {
        mainLoading: {
          "0%": {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
          "50%": {
            "background-position": "100% 0%",
          },
          "100%": {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix: "tw-",
};
```

```html
<div class="tw-absolute tw-top-0 tw-left-0 tw-w-full tw-h-full tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-text-center tw-justify-center tw-z-20 tw-bg-gradient-to-r tw-from-white tw-via-gray-300 tw-bg-size-200 tw-animate-mainLoading tw-bg-[length:200%_100%]">
```

See this working in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZWitDnrEk6).